# Manipulate multiindex column in pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, reshape

I see this question asked multiple times but solutions from other questions did not worked!

I have data frame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"date": ["20180920"] * 3 + ["20180921"] * 3,
"id": ["A12","A123","A1234","A12345","A123456","A0"],
"mean": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
"std" :[7,8,9,10,11,12],
"test": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
"result": [70, 90, 110, "(-)", "(+)", 0.3],})
```

[image: df]

using `pivot_table`

```
df_sum_table = (pd.pivot_table(df,index=['id'], columns = ['date'], values = ['mean','std']))
```

I got

[image]

```
df_sum_table.columns

MultiIndex([('mean', '20180920'),
        ('mean', '20180921'),
        ( 'std', '20180920'),
        ( 'std', '20180921')],
       names=[None, 'date'])
```

So I wanted to shift `date` column one row below and remove `id` row. but keep `id` name there.
by following these past solutions

[ValueError when trying to have multi-index in DataFrame.pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069315/valueerror-when-trying-to-have-multi-index-in-dataframe-pivot)

[Removing index name from df created with pivot_table()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906822/removing-index-name-from-df-created-with-pivot-table)

[Resetting index to flat after pivot_table in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630255/resetting-index-to-flat-after-pivot-table-in-pandas)

[pandas pivot_table keep index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729856/pandas-pivot-table-keep-index)

```
df_sum_table = (pd.pivot_table(df,index=['id'], columns = ['date'], values = ['mean','std'])).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

but getting error

> TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`.

How can I remove `date` but keep the `id` in the first column ?

The desired output

[image]

@jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `rename_axis`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['id'], columns = ['date'], values = ['mean', 'std']).rename_axis(columns={'date': None}).fillna('').reset_index().T.reset_index(level=1).T.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index(drop=True)
df.index = df.pop('id').replace('', 'id').tolist()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             mean      mean       std       std
id       20180920  20180921  20180920  20180921
A0                        6                  12
A12             1                   7          
A123            2                   8          
A1234           3                   9          
A12345                    4                  10
A123456                   5                  11
```

You could use `rename_axis` and rename the specific column axis name with dictionary mapping. I specify the columns argument for column axis name mapping.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! Can we make the table like in OP ? the last excel table

Comment: @Alexander Just add `fillna('')`

Comment: @Alexander I added it

Comment: Really! I don't see any change with fillna('') and without. Can you please confirm as well ? That shift I really need!

Comment: @Alexander `fillna` changes the NaNs to `''`, is it that you want the columns duplicated?

Comment: what ever makes that desired output!

Comment: @Alexander Wait 10 mins sorry have to leave a bit

Comment: wow I did not imagine such a multiple rename code :)) `.rename_axis(columns={'date': None}).fillna('').reset_index().T.reset_index(level=1).T.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index(drop=True)`